Restitution and inelastic collisions
If particle $A$ and particle $B$ collides in plane or space, we can calculate the impulse $\vec{J}$ from $B$ to $A$ with
$$
\vec{J}=\frac{((\vec{v}_A-\vec{v}_B)\cdot\hat{n})(\epsilon+1)} {\frac{1}{m_a}+\frac{1}{m_b}}\hat{n}
$$
where $\epsilon$ is the coefficient of restitution, $\vec{v}_A$ and $\vec{v}_B$ is the initial velocities of $A$ and $B$ and $\hat{n}$ is the normalised normal vector of $B$ at the point of collision. With this $\vec{J}$, we can calculate the final speed of $A$, $\vec{v}_{Af}$ just as $\vec{v}_{Af}=\vec{v}_A+\frac{1}{m_A}\vec{J}$
However, in a perfectly inelastic collision, i.e $\epsilon=0$, we expect the particles to be glued together with a common velocity. This formula does not predict that in 2D or more (in 1D, yes), so my questions are:

Why isn't the formula above valid in more dimensions than 1D when $\epsilon=0$?
In which situations are the formula valid? Since it is not valid for $\epsilon=0$, why should it be valid for any $\epsilon<1$?


I think you are just wrong. You should use the reduced mass formalism to change to a parametrisation of the problem in such a way that the conservation of linear momentum is automatically enforced, and the coefficient of restitution inserted so that you can prove properties of the general collision. Then you should obtain that the formula works in 3+1D.

I found it. The formula is derived from the fact that the change of momentum is in the collision normal vector direction. $\epsilon=0$ means that the relative velocity of the particles are zero along the normal vector after collision. But each particle may still have a velocity component orthogonal to that normal and therefore not be stuck together.
First, I go through the elastic collision:

We can state that the change in velocities are due to the interaction between $A$ and $B$. The impulse on A is defined by $\vec{J}=m_A(\vec{u}_A-\vec{v}_A)$ with the initial velocity $\vec{v}_A$ and velocity after collision $\vec{u}_A$.
The relative velocity of the particles before collision is $\vec{v}_\text{rel}=\vec{v}_A-\vec{v}_B$, that is the velocity of $A$, as seen from $B$.
We project the relative velocity in the direction of the impulse of $A$. Given this direction as the normalised vector $\hat{n}$, the magnitude of the projection is $\vec{v}_\text{rel}\cdot\hat{n}$ and the vector, of course, $(\vec{v}_\text{rel}\cdot\hat{n})\hat{n}$.
On reflection, we may have a restitution, a number denoted $\epsilon$; where $\epsilon\in[0,1]$. A restitution of 1 means a perfectly elastic collision (no loss of energy), and a restitution of 0 means a perfectly. inelastic collision, meaning that no bouncing will occur.
By definition of $\epsilon$, the relative velocity along $\hat{n}$ after the collision is $(\vec{u}_\text{rel}\cdot\hat{n})\hat{n}=-\epsilon(\vec{v}_\text{rel}\cdot\hat{n})\hat{n}$.
The difference in each object's linear momentum along $\hat{n}$ is:

$$\Delta \vec{P}_A\hat{n}=m_A((\vec{u}_A-\vec{v}_A)\cdot\hat{n})\hat{n}\Rightarrow J\hat{n}= m_A((\vec{u}_A-\vec{v}_A)\cdot\hat{n})\hat{n}\Rightarrow \vec{u}_A\hat{n}=(\vec{v}_A\cdot\hat{n}+\frac{\vec{J}\cdot\hat{n}}{m_A})\hat{n}\hspace{4mm}(1)$$
$$\Delta \vec{P}_B\hat{n}=m_B((\vec{u}_B-\vec{v}_B)\cdot\hat{n})\hat{n}\Rightarrow -J\hat{n}= m_B((\vec{u}_B-\vec{v}_B)\cdot\hat{n})\hat{n}\Rightarrow \vec{u}_B\hat{n}=(\vec{v}_B\cdot\hat{n}-\frac{\vec{J}\cdot\hat{n}}{m_B})\hat{n}\hspace{3mm}(2)$$

The relative velocity after collision, along the normal, is $(\vec{u}_\text{rel}\cdot\hat{n})\hat{n}=(\vec{u}_A\cdot\hat{n}-\vec{u}_B\cdot\hat{n})\hat{n}$

We apply this difference in (1) and (2) above and get $(\vec{u}_\text{rel}\cdot\hat{n})\hat{n}=(\vec{v}_A-\vec{v}_B)\hat{n}+\vec{J}(\frac{1}{m_A}+\frac{1}{m_B})\hat{n}$

Solving for $J\hat{n}$ gives $\vec{J}=\frac{-\vec{v}_\text{rel}(\epsilon+1)\cdot\hat{n}}{\frac{1}{m_A}+\frac{1}{m_B}}\hat{n}$, which is the impulse on $A$ by the definition in the first bullet point above. The impulse on $B$ is then $-\vec{J}$.


This formula applies when the impulse is orthogonal to the object's surface. But if there is a tangential component of the impulse (maybe due to friction), expressed with the normalised vector $\hat{t}$ we need to take it to account so
$$
\vec{J}= \frac{-\vec{v}_\text{rel}(\epsilon+1)\cdot\hat{n}}{\frac{1}{m_A}+\frac{1}{m_B}}\hat{n} + \frac{-\vec{v}_\text{rel}(\epsilon+1)\cdot\hat{t}}{\frac{1}{m_A}+\frac{1}{m_B}}\hat{t}
$$
When $\epsilon=0$, i.e an inelastic collision, there is a tangential component.
Example
Given objects $A$ and $B$ where
$m_A=m_B=1$, $\vec{v}_A=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$, $\vec{v}_B=\begin{bmatrix}-1\\-2\end{bmatrix}$, $\hat{n}=\begin{bmatrix}-\sqrt{2}/2\\-\sqrt{2}/2\end{bmatrix}$ and $\hat{t}=\begin{bmatrix}-\sqrt{2}/2\\\sqrt{2}/2\end{bmatrix}$

Case $\epsilon=1$:
Impulse on $A$:
$$
\vec{J}_A=\frac{-\begin{bmatrix} 0-(-1)\\1-(-2)\end{bmatrix}(1+1)\cdot\begin{bmatrix} -\sqrt{2}/2\\-\sqrt{2}/2\end{bmatrix}}{\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{1}} \begin{bmatrix} -\sqrt{2}/2\\-\sqrt{2}/2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -2\\-2\end{bmatrix}
$$
Velocity on $A$ after collision:
$$
\vec{v}_A+\frac{1}{m_A}\vec{J}_A=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} -2\\-2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -2\\-1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
Impulse on $B$:
$$
\vec{J}_B = -\vec{J}_A = \begin{bmatrix} 2\\2 \end{bmatrix}
$$
Velocity on $B$ after collision:
$$
\vec{v}_B+\frac{1}{m_B}\vec{J}_B=\begin{bmatrix} -1\\-2 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 2\\2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\0 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Case $\epsilon=0$:
Impulse on $A$:
$$
\vec{J}_A=\frac{-\begin{bmatrix} 0-(-1)\\1-(-2)\end{bmatrix}(0+1)\cdot\begin{bmatrix} -\sqrt{2}/2\\-\sqrt{2}/2\end{bmatrix}}{\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{1}} \begin{bmatrix} -\sqrt{2}/2\\-\sqrt{2}/2\end{bmatrix} + \frac{-\begin{bmatrix} 0-(-1)\\1-(-2)\end{bmatrix}(0+1)\cdot\begin{bmatrix} -\sqrt{2}/2\\\sqrt{2}/2\end{bmatrix}}{\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{1}} \begin{bmatrix} -\sqrt{2}/2\\\sqrt{2}/2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -1/2\\-3/2\end{bmatrix}
$$
Velocity on $A$ after collision:
$$
\vec{v}_A+\frac{1}{m_A}\vec{J}_A=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} -1/2\\-3/2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -1/2\\-1/2 \end{bmatrix}
$$
Impulse on $B$:
$$
\vec{J}_B = -\vec{J}_A = \begin{bmatrix} 1/2\\3/2 \end{bmatrix}
$$
Velocity on $B$ after collision:
$$
\vec{v}_B+\frac{1}{m_B}\vec{J}_B=\begin{bmatrix} -1\\-2 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 1/2\\3/2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -1/2\\-1/2 \end{bmatrix}
$$
Here, we need to take account of the tangential interaction due to the inelastic collision. The result is the same velocity on each object (i.e their relative velocity is 0), as expected after a purely inelastic collision.
[

For a perfectly inelastic collision, you need two components of impulse, one along the contact normal as stated, and one along the slip plane. Combined they force the relative speed of the two particles to be zero.

The impulse component along the slip plane was the key I needed. If you post that as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks, @JohnAlexiou

Just award your own answer. Maybe you can add some more details if you want.

Thanks again! I updated my answer with a derivation of the formula and an example collision, elastic as well as inelastic, where I calculated the final velocities. @JohnAlexiou
